# OpenCV + FFTW - magnitude image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, fftw

#### Hello again.

Today I'm working on extending my simple OpenCV image processing application. I would like to calculate phase and magnitude of my loaded cv::Mat. I have to use FFTW c++ library for this purpose (i know about dft in OpenCV).

My work is based on tutorial: http://www.admindojo.com/discrete-fourier-transform-in-c-with-fftw/

#### What's my problem

So according to tutorial my output magnitude should be like:
[image]

Unfortunately my output is quite different:
[image]

On the other hand, image of phase is almost the same as tutorial image so this part is good.

#### Code and My thoughts

Take a look on the most important code: (what am I doing there is trying to port tutorial as it is to work with OpenCV)

EDITED: (Both posts merged)
Ok. So I changed code a bit, but output is still different from the tutorial.
Take a look at the code:

```
void Processing::fft_moc(cv::Mat &pixels, cv::Mat &outMag, cv::Mat outPhase, int mode)
{
int squareSize = pixels.cols;

fftw_plan planR, planG, planB;
fftw_complex *inR, *inG, *inB, *outR, *outG, *outB;

// allocate input arrays
inB = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * squareSize * squareSize);
inG = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * squareSize * squareSize);
inR = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * squareSize * squareSize);

// allocate output arrays
outB = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * squareSize * squareSize);
outG = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * squareSize * squareSize);
outR = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * squareSize * squareSize);

if (mode == FFT)
{
    // create plans
    planB = fftw_plan_dft_2d(squareSize, squareSize, inR, outB, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    planG = fftw_plan_dft_2d(squareSize, squareSize, inG, outG, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    planR = fftw_plan_dft_2d(squareSize, squareSize, inB, outR, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
}

// assig1n values to real parts (values between 0 and MaxRGB)
for( int x = 0; x < pixels.rows; x++ )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < pixels.cols; y++ )
    {
        double blue = pixels.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[0];
        double green = pixels.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[1];
        double red = pixels.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[2];

        // save as real numbers
        inB[squareSize*x+y][0] = blue;
        inG[squareSize*x+y][0] = green;
        inR[squareSize*x+y][0] = red;
    }
}

// perform FORWARD fft
fftw_execute(planB);
fftw_execute(planG);
fftw_execute(planR);


double ***outMagF=new double**[pixels.rows];
for(int i = 0 ; i < pixels.rows ; i++)
{
    outMagF[i]=new double *[pixels.cols];
    for(int j = 0 ; j < pixels.cols ; j++)
    {
        outMagF[i][j]= new double[3];
    }
}

//calculate magnitude
//find min and max for each channel

double n_minG = 0.0;
double n_maxG = 0.0;
double n_minB = 0.0;
double n_maxB = 0.0;
double n_minR = 0.0;
double n_maxR = 0.0;

for( int x = 0; x < pixels.rows; x++ )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < pixels.cols; y++ )
    {

        int i = squareSize*x+y;

        // normalize values
        double realB = outB[i][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
        double imagB = outB[i][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);

        double realG = outG[i][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
        double imagG = outG[i][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);

        double realR = outR[i][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
        double imagR = outR[i][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);

        // magnitude
        double magB = log(1+sqrt((realB * realB) + (imagB * imagB)));
        double magG = log(1+sqrt((realG * realG) + (imagG * imagG)));
        double magR = log(1+sqrt((realR * realR) + (imagR * imagR)));

        n_minB = n_minB > magB ? magB : n_minB;
        n_maxB = n_maxB < magB ? magB : n_maxB;

        n_minG = n_minG > magG ? magG : n_minG;
        n_maxG = n_maxG < magG ? magG : n_maxG;

        n_minR = n_minR > magR ? magR : n_minR;
        n_maxR = n_maxR < magR ? magR : n_maxR;

        outMagF[x][y][0] = magB;
        outMagF[x][y][1] = magG;
        outMagF[x][y][2] = magR;
    }
}

for( int x = 0; x < pixels.rows; x++ )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < pixels.cols; y++ )
    {
        int i = squareSize*x+y;

        double realB = outB[i][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
        double imagB = outB[i][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);

        double realG = outG[i][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
        double imagG = outG[i][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);

        double realR = outR[i][0] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);
        double imagR = outR[i][1] / (double)(squareSize * squareSize);

        // write normalized to output = (value-min)/(max-min)
        outMag.at<cv::Vec3f>(x,y)[0] = (double)(outMagF[x][y][0]-n_minB)/(n_maxB-n_minB);
        outMag.at<cv::Vec3f>(x,y)[1] = (double)(outMagF[x][y][1]-n_minG)/(n_maxG-n_minG);
        outMag.at<cv::Vec3f>(x,y)[2] = (double)(outMagF[x][y][2]-n_minR)/(n_maxR-n_minR);

        // std::complex for arg()
        std::complex<double> cB(realB, imagB);
        std::complex<double> cG(realG, imagG);
        std::complex<double> cR(realR, imagR);

        // phase
        double phaseB = arg(cB) + M_PI;
        double phaseG = arg(cG) + M_PI;
        double phaseR = arg(cR) + M_PI;

        // scale and write to output
        outPhase.at<cv::Vec3f>(x,y)[0] = (phaseB / (double)(2 * M_PI)) * 1;
        outPhase.at<cv::Vec3f>(x,y)[1] = (phaseG / (double)(2 * M_PI)) * 1;
        outPhase.at<cv::Vec3f>(x,y)[2] = (phaseR / (double)(2 * M_PI)) * 1;
    }
}

// move zero frequency to (squareSize/2, squareSize/2)
swapQuadrants(squareSize, outMag);
swapQuadrants(squareSize, outPhase);

// free memory
fftw_destroy_plan(planR);
fftw_destroy_plan(planG);
fftw_destroy_plan(planB);
fftw_free(inR); fftw_free(outR);
fftw_free(inG); fftw_free(outG);
fftw_free(inB); fftw_free(outB);
}
```

I store the final output in cv::Mat with type CV_32FC3. And Yes, the way I normalize magnitude is quite ugly but I just wanted to be sure that everything is working like I expect.

Take a look at my output again:

[image]

So as You can see I still need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You assign computed values to uchar variables and you loosing precision and all negative values and values above 255 are also lost.
Try make your computations in real valued variables, then normalize the final result to range 0-255 and then assign it to the result image of type CV_8U.

Comment: I changed to: CV_32FC3. After that I checked that my output right after log() is always above 0. So I don't know where the problem lies. Normalization in that case is 0-1 range.

Comment: You still have  outMag.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[0] = magB; it will truncated, before you perform normalization.

Comment: Proper code was in second post of my. Never mind now, I merged both post so code is updated. Still doesn't work. Take a look plz. I'm pretty sure now that nothing is cutted or losted.

Answer (score 0):

FFT planes usually contain a very large difference between the 0th elements (the DC) which is very large, and the rest of the elements which are usually close to zero.

When displaying the magnitude it is common practice to actually show the log of the magnitude so that large values are reduce more strongly than small ones.
The tutorial states this explicitly: *"The magnitude appears to be black but isn’t. To make the information visible we scale the image logarithmically."*

You need to display the log of the values to see a similar image.

Comment: Actually I do log scaling (or I believe i do):
 // magnitude
 double magB = log(1+sqrt((realB * realB) + (imagB * imagB)));
 double magG = log(1+sqrt((realG * realG) + (imagG * imagG)));
 double magR = log(1+sqrt((realR * realR) + (imagR * imagR)));